# asp.net Core - ModelState.IsValid is requiring fields from other tables even though they are not required in the DB

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

When I attempt to create a "TblCompanyInfo" record I am getting an error that "The TblOutdialSetting field is required.". I assume it has to do with the foreign key that exists on TblCompanyInfo. However, this key should only require a matching CompanyID from TblCompanyInfo when you create a new record in TblOutdialSettings.  I am not trying to create a new record for TblOutdialSettings, only TblCompanyInfo.

Here is my foreign key
[image]

Here is my controller

```
 // GET: Company/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        TblCompanyInfo tblcompanyinfo = new TblCompanyInfo();
        return View(tblcompanyinfo);
    }

        // POST: Company/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("CompanyId,Username,Password,CompanyName,ContactFirstName,ContactLastName,ContactPriPhone,ContactPriPhoneExt,ContactSecPhone,ContactSecPhoneExt,ContactEmail,Address1,Address2,City,State,Zipcode,CompanyPhone,LogoFile,Htmlcolor,CompanyUrl,CompanyEmail,AgreeToTou,AuthNetcustomerProfileId,AuthNetcustomerPaymentProfileId,PaymentInfoValid,DateTimeSignedUp,Active,TestMode,BizAcctFreeRemCount,AcctTypeId,InTrial,CompanyStatusId,OnHold,OnHoldReasonId,OnHoldStartDate")] TblCompanyInfo tblcompanyinfo)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(tblcompanyinfo);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var error in ViewData.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(modelState => modelState.Errors)) 
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
   
        return View(tblcompanyinfo);
    }
```

Here is my View

```
    @model AppointmentRemindersNetCoreMVC.Models.TblCompanyInfo

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

@*@Html.ValidationSummary(true)*@

<h4>TblCompanyInfo</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Username" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Username" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Username" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Password" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CompanyName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="CompanyName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CompanyName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ContactFirstName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ContactFirstName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ContactFirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ContactLastName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ContactLastName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ContactLastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ContactPriPhone" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ContactPriPhone" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ContactPriPhone" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ContactPriPhoneExt" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ContactPriPhoneExt" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ContactPriPhoneExt" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ContactSecPhone" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ContactSecPhone" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ContactSecPhone" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ContactSecPhoneExt" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ContactSecPhoneExt" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ContactSecPhoneExt" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ContactEmail" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ContactEmail" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ContactEmail" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Address1" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Address1" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Address1" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Address2" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Address2" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Address2" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="City" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="City" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="City" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="State" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="State" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="State" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Zipcode" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Zipcode" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Zipcode" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CompanyPhone" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="CompanyPhone" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CompanyPhone" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="AgreeToTou" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AgreeToTou)
                </label>
            </div>
            @
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Here is my TblCompanyInfo.cs class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace AppointmentRemindersNetCoreMVC.Models
{
    public partial class TblCompanyInfo
    {
        public TblCompanyInfo()
        {
            TblCalendarData = new HashSet<TblCalendarDatum>();
            TblClientVoicefiles = new HashSet<TblClientVoicefile>();
            TblCompanyToBillingItems = new HashSet<TblCompanyToBillingItem>();
            TblEnglishSpanishMappings = new HashSet<TblEnglishSpanishMapping>();
            TblEvents = new HashSet<TblEvent>();
            TblImportData = new HashSet<TblImportDatum>();
            TblImportLogs = new HashSet<TblImportLog>();
            TblNoReminderLists = new HashSet<TblNoReminderList>();
            TblReportData = new HashSet<TblReportDatum>();
            TblResellerPaymentCustomerCompanies = new HashSet<TblResellerPayment>();
            TblResellerPaymentResellerCompanies = new HashSet<TblResellerPayment>();
            TblResellerToCompanyCompanies = new HashSet<TblResellerToCompany>();
            TblResellerToCompanySalesCompanies = new HashSet<TblResellerToCompany>();
            TblRules = new HashSet<TblRule>();
        }

        public long CompanyId { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Password { get; set; } = null!;
        public string CompanyName { get; set; } = null!;
        public string ContactFirstName { get; set; } = null!;
        public string ContactLastName { get; set; } = null!;
        public string ContactPriPhone { get; set; } = null!;
        public string? ContactPriPhoneExt { get; set; }
        public string? ContactSecPhone { get; set; }
        public string? ContactSecPhoneExt { get; set; }
        public string? ContactEmail { get; set; }
        public string? Address1 { get; set; }
        public string? Address2 { get; set; }
        public string? City { get; set; }
        public string? State { get; set; }
        public string? Zipcode { get; set; }
        public string? CompanyPhone { get; set; }
        public string? LogoFile { get; set; }
        public string? Htmlcolor { get; set; }
        public string? CompanyUrl { get; set; }
        public string? CompanyEmail { get; set; }
        public bool AgreeToTou { get; set; }
        public string? AuthNetcustomerProfileId { get; set; }
        public string? AuthNetcustomerPaymentProfileId { get; set; }
        public bool PaymentInfoValid { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTimeSignedUp { get; set; }
        public bool? Active { get; set; }
        public bool TestMode { get; set; }
        public int BizAcctFreeRemCount { get; set; }
        public int AcctTypeId { get; set; }
        public bool? InTrial { get; set; }
        public int CompanyStatusId { get; set; }
        public bool OnHold { get; set; }
        public int OnHoldReasonId { get; set; }
        public DateTime OnHoldStartDate { get; set; }

        public virtual TblAcctType? AcctType { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual TblCompanyStatusId? CompanyStatus { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual TblOnHoldReason? OnHoldReason { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual TblBillingTypeToCompany? TblBillingTypeToCompany { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual TblOutdialSetting? TblOutdialSetting { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual ICollection<TblCalendarDatum> TblCalendarData { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TblClientVoicefile> TblClientVoicefiles { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TblCompanyToBillingItem> TblCompanyToBillingItems { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TblEnglishSpanishMapping> TblEnglishSpanishMappings { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TblEvent> TblEvents { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TblImportDatum> TblImportData { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TblImportLog> TblImportLogs { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TblNoReminderList> TblNoReminderLists { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TblReportDatum> TblReportData { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TblResellerPayment> TblResellerPaymentCustomerCompanies { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TblResellerPayment> TblResellerPaymentResellerCompanies { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TblResellerToCompany> TblResellerToCompanyCompanies { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TblResellerToCompany> TblResellerToCompanySalesCompanies { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TblRule> TblRules { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are probably using Net 6. You can remove option nullable from project configuration

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <!--<Nullable>enable</Nullable>-->
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

or make nullable your problem properties. But in this case you will probably have to do this to most properties in your another classes too

```
public TblOutdialSetting? TblOutdialSetting {get; set;}
```

and fix create code. Try to use this syntax. Ef sometimes can't figure what table to update if you don't put it explicitly.

```
_context.Set<TblCompanyInfo>().Add(tblcompanyinfo);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

and IMHO you have to remove [Bind] from the action. I don' t see any sense in using this.

Comment: Thanks - I commented out the <Nullable>enable</Nullable> and now it passes the model check but when it tries to execute the line "await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); "  it thows this error SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CompanyID', table 'ApptReminder.dbo.tblOutdialSettings'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

Comment: @Zenacity it is an SQL database exception already. Your db table CompanyId column should  allow null . You can fix it by using SqlServer management studio or make companyId nullable  ( int? CompanyId) and repeat db migration.

Comment: But I dont want to write to the tblOutdialSettings table at all - I only want to create a record in the tblCompanyInfo table

Comment: You have to post tblCompanyInfo class too. I can not tell what to fix since I can not see data

Comment: @Zenacity I updated my answer. Try to use this syntax.

Comment: Thanks - So if I change public virtual TblOutdialSetting TblOutdialSetting { get; set; } = null!; to public virtual TblOutdialSetting? TblOutdialSetting { get; set; } = null!; - it works. This is in the TblCompanyInfo.cs model class.  however when I rerun scoffolding (in case of any DB changes) it sets it back.  Is there something I need to do in the DB to allow it to scaffold as null ?

Comment: @Zenacity Pls show me your classes I don't know what is wrong with them.

Comment: @Zenacity If you have not changed, you don't need to set blOutdialSetting { get; set; } = null!; it is null by default. The same for another reference properties. You can make all Ids null just  by setting int? Id